# MSChart SuspendUpdates not working

Tags: mschart

I am trying to use series.SuspendUpdates to prevent redrawing on every added data point although it doesn't seem to be doing anything.   it still repaints for every added point as if nothing is suspended.

Answer (score 0):

It works just fine here. Show your code!

Note that there is no `someSeries.SuspendUpdates`, only a

```
someSeries.Points.SuspendUpdates()
```

or

```
someChart.Series.SuspendUpdates()
```

as the function works only on `ChartElementCollections`.

See [here for MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd467742.aspx)

Also note that it is up to you to keep track of those `SuspendUpdates` and `ResumeUpdates` calls as the state gets **stacked**, so you need to **balance** them:

> If you call the SuspendUpdates method several times, you will need to
>   call the ResumeUpdates method an equal number of times.